# How to implement Google Analytics for an electron based windows app using universal-analytics?

Tags: windows, google-analytics, electron, universal-analytics

I want to implement google analytics on my windows app which is primarily built using electron based front-end and Java Spring-boot based back-end. I was not able to find suitable solutions for the same online.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **Measurement Protocol**, a standard set of rules for collecting and sending hits from any internet-connected device to Analytics: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6086079?hl=en

Comment: I was able to make it work with this giude for GA4  and Measurement protocol v2 https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/sending-events?client_type=gtag#send_an_event

Comment: Ok, but GA4 is not Universal Analytics as was requested in the question.